# How to add a buffer with fixed size in pixels using leaflet and turf

Tags: leaflet, turfjs

I'm trying to create a buffer with fixed size using leaflet and turf, the buffer should be created when the mapClick event is emitted, so basically a buffer is created when I click the map

when creating a buffer or a circle you need to pass a radius property which is pretty much the "size" of the buffer, which can be in Kilometers, Meters, Miles and so on

**The problem is:** I need the buffer to always be the same size in pixels regardless of the mapZoom or Scale, for instance, using circle:

```
const center = [LatlongFromMouseEvent];
const radius = 5;
const options = {steps: 10, units: 'kilometers', properties: {foo: 'bar'}};
const circle = turf.circle(center, radius, options);
```

OR using buffer

```
const point = turf.point([LatlongFromMouseEvent]);
const buffered = turf.buffer(point, 5, {units: 'kilometers'});
```

OR using native Leaflet "Circle" constructor

```
 const lCircle = new Circle([event.latlng.lat, event.latlng.lng], {
 color: 'red',
 fillColor: '#f03',
 fillOpacity: 0.5,
 radius: 500
})

  lCircle.addTo(mapInstance)
```

All of those "buffers" will change it's size depending on the level of zoom of the map

AND "circleMarker" from leaflet automatically changes size when you change the zoom

Comment: So what's the units of the size of the "buffer", pixels or meters?

Comment: Pixels would be ideal, but there's no unit size for "pixels" on turf or leaflet

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#circlemarker-radius

Comment: CircleMarker wont work for me, I also need the buffer polygon, I already tried CircleMarker with tools like circleToPolygon and it just converts the tiny point to a polygon and not the whole buffer with the radius

Comment: You want something like https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset then.

Comment: I see, but this one seems to be only for polyline, I'm working with CircleMarker Or Circle

Comment: This is approaching a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please reframe your problem (i.e. *why* doesn't CircleMarker cut it?).

Comment: Has to be a circle, has to be a polygon, has to be fixed sized in pixels, regular "radius" options in units like "km/meters..." won't work because the circle has to always be the same size regardless of the current mapzoom.

CircleMarker changes sizes when the map changes and also it's not a polygon, only a circle with radius

Comment: Found the solution by using the metersPerPixel formula , I'll be updating the post now, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by using the metersPerPixel formula

```
const zoom = map.getZoom()
const lat = map.getCenter().lat
const metersPerPixel = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(lat * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, zoom)
const radius = metersPerPixel * sizeInPixels
```

More info about the formula in:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to